# How to add EditText's with constraints onClick

Tags: java, android, xml, onclick, android-edittext

I'm trying to calculate the average based on user input. Now I've got the basics working. But I want to add 2 EditTexts with constraints when clicking  the addGradeButton. I have searched for a view hours but can't find anything to do this. Could someone help me with doing this in general.

Any explanation or tips etc. are welcome!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUJsi.jpg)

```
final TextView averageView = findViewById(R.id.averageView); 
final String averageText = getString(R.string.average); 
final Button calculateButton = findViewById(R.id.calculateAverageButton); 
final Button addGradeButton = findViewById(R.id.addGradeButton)

calaculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() { 
    @SupressLint("SetTextI18n")                                                     
    public void onClick(View v) { 

        double grade[]  = {Double.parseDouble(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.grade1)).getText().toString()); 

        double weight[] = {Double.parseDouble(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight1)).getText().toString()); 

        double weightTotal = weight[0]; double sum = grade[0] * weight[0] 

        double average = sum / weightTotal 

        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") String averageResult = String.format(%.2f, average);

        averageView.setText(averageText + " " + averageResult);
```

Comment: `But I want to add 2 EditTexts with constraints onClick of the addGradeButton` can't understand what u mean by this elaborate.

Comment: @Anmol maybe the screenshot I added can clarify some?